# Why does this template have an error in Xcode but not Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-c++, templates

I am getting an error in Xcode when using templates in C++. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

The first version reports an error in Xcode, but not in Visual Studio.

```
// Version 1: Error in Xcode, but not Visual Studio
template<typename LengthT, typename VertexT> 
int MyGraphAlgorithm(...arguments omitted...)
{
  using namespace boost;

  typedef property<vertex_distance_t, LengthT> VertextProperties_t;
  typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, VertextProperties_t> Graph;
  // In next line Xcode reports: "error: expected `;' before 'vertexInitial'"
  graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertexInitial(100);
}
```

The second has no error.  The difference is the use of the template parameter *LengthT* in a templated typedef.

```
// Version 2: No error in Xcode or Visual Studio
template<typename LengthT, typename VertexT> 
int MyGraphAlgorithm(...arguments omitted...)
{
  using namespace boost;

  // In the following line, LengthT has been changed to int
  typedef property<vertex_distance_t, int> VertextProperties_t;
  typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, VertextProperties_t> Graph;
  graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor  vertexInitial(100);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the compiler has no clue what `graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor` **is**. Is it a static member or a type? If it's a type then you must say so:

```
typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor
```

The reason the compiler isn't smart enough to figure it out on its own is because `LengthT` is a template parameter. It can be *anything*, and so at the time of template declaration the compiler can't tell what its value is going to be, and the typedef is thus ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

`vertex_descriptor` is a dependent type (it depends on the template argument `LengthT`), thus you have to use `typename`:

```
typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertexInitial(100);
```

In the second example the depency on the template argument is removed (you use a fixed type instead - `int`), thus there is no error.

A much simpler way to reproduce that:

```
template<class T> struct A { typedef T type; };
template<class T> struct B { 
    A<T>::type t1; // wrong, works with VS but not with conforming compilers
    typename A<T>::type t2; // correct
};
```

Visual Studio is known to be non-conforming in that regard and is *"great"* for developing non-portable template code.

Comment: I suspected it was a nonstandard VS "extension".  Thanks for the info.